# setInterval function increments values twice on restarting setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

There is a code that I am trying to run which creates a popup. Once the popup opens, a counter is initialized which increments every second and uses setInterval. However when I cancel the process(clearInterval along with it) and reopen the popup, the counter initializes but increments twice every second. You can find my jquery script below for refernece. Please let me know why am I observing this strange behaviour. Please forgive the the dirty code and if my jquery practices are wrong and feel free to point it out. I am considerably new to front-end development and hence it might be a trivial issue, but I can't seem to find any reasons online. Looking forward to any inputs.

```
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting

// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery

;
(function($) {
                var counter2 = 0;
                var counter3 = 60;
                var counter4 = 60;
                var interval2;
                var timeNow;
                var canFlag = 0;
    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        var checker = '';
        var popClicked = 0;
        var timeout = 0;
        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#my-button').bind('click', function(e) {
            checker = $('#log').text();
            popClicked = 1;


            if (checker==="somecondition") {
                //alert(checker);
                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('.element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
            }
            else {
                alert('Oops.. error message');
            }


        });



        $('#popNext').click(function() {
            currTopic = randTopic();
            $('#newTopic').html(currTopic);
            $('#pg1pop').hide();
            $('#pg2pop').show();
            var counter = 10;
            var counterFlag = 0;

            $('#pg2Ref').click(function() {
                currTopic = randTopic();
                $('#newTopic').html(currTopic);
                counter = 10;
            });
            $('.b-modal, .b-close').click(function() {
                canProcess();
                $('#pg2pop').hide();

                $('#timeout').hide();

                $('#pg1pop').show();

            });
            $('#pg2Cont').click(function() {

                counter2 = 0;
                counter3 = 60;
                counter4 = 60;

                counterFlag = 1;
                $('#pg2pop').hide();
                $('#pg3pop').show();


                //alert("counter 1-4: "+counter+"-"+counter2+"-"+counter3+"-"+counter4+"-"+"cflag - "+counterFlag+"-"+"timeout flag"+timeout);

                interval2 = setInterval(function() {

                        counter2++;



                    if (counter2 == 146) {
                        // Display a login box
                        timeNow = (new Date).getTime();
                        $('#pg3con').html('Well done!<br>Process is over. Please wait, we are processing your data. ');
                        clearInterval(interval2);
                        stopProcess(currTopic);
                    }

                    else if (counter2 == 1) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Your topic is:<br>"' + currTopic + '"<br>& you have <span id="sec2" style="font-size:120%;">60</span> seconds to start!<br><br><button id="skip" style="width: auto; margin:auto">Skip</button>');

                        $('#skip').click(function() {
                            counter2 = 53;
                        });
                    }
                    else if (counter2 > 1 && counter2 <= 53) {
                        counter4--;
                        $('#sec2').html(counter4);
                    }
                    else if (counter2 == 54) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Relax! ');

                    }
                    else if (counter2 == 58) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Your time starts in 3..');

                    }
                    else if (counter2 == 59) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Your time starts in 2..');
                    }
                    else if (counter2 == 60) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Your time starts in 1..');
                    }
                    else if (counter2 == 61 && timeout == 0) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('<div class="w40" class="tCenter"><p>Your topic:<p><br><p>' + currTopic + '</p></div><div class="w60"><div>You have<br></div><div id="sec" style="font-size:600%;">60</div><div> Secs</div></div><br><br><button class="contentBox contentBoxOrange" id="continue" style="width: auto; margin:auto">Continue</button>');
                        $('#popupLog').show();
                        $('#continue').click(function() {
                            counter2 = 121;
                        });


                        startProcess();
                    }
                    else if (counter2 > 61 && counter2 <= 121) {
                        counter3--;
                        $('#sec').html(counter3);
                    }
                    else if (counter2 > 121 && counter2 < 146) {
                        $('#pg3con').html('Some text:<br>"Some text"<br><br><button id="finish" style="width: auto; margin:auto">Finish</button>');
                         $('#finish').click(function() {
                            counter2 = 145;
                        });
                    }
                    $('.b-modal, .b-close').click(function() {
                    canProcess();
                    canFlag =1;
                    clearInterval(interval2);
                    $('#pg3con').html('<img src="path/to/images/ajax-loader.gif">');

                    $('#pg3pop').hide();
                    $('#pg1pop').show();

                });
                }, 1000);




            });
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                if(counter > 0){
                    counter--;
                }
                $('#secs').html(counter + " seconds");
                if (counter === 0 && counterFlag === 0) {
                    // Display a login box
                    timeout = 1;
counterFlag = 1;
                    clearInterval(interval);

                    $('#pg2pop').hide();
                    $('#popupLog').hide();
                    $('#timeout').show();


                }
            }, 1000);

        });



    });

})(jQuery);
```

Reproducible : Always;
Probable cause : Lack of knowledge/logical error

EDIT: The counter increments by 3 if cancelled twice, and so on.

Comment: You should show the relevant script part that is causing the error.

Comment: We can't debug your entire code for you. Singling out the problematic area and writing a reproduction is your task. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Tomalak: I felt that I have placed the problematic area. Should I put code for other files here or lesser??

Comment: Is there something really wrong that I am doing here?? I have 4 downvotes but no clear suggestions. At least let me know what the issue is with the question

Comment: Have you read the link I posted? You did nothing of the things that were in there. You dropped a big chunk of your code into your question, unmodified, along with "this doesn't work". That's what got you the down votes. Had you tried to analyze your problem and reproduce it in a few lines, things would have gone differently.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is my window.setInterval function overlapping itself in the DOM when called multiple times?](/q/53856593/4642212).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not reproduced or tested your entire script (as mentioned in the comments, we are not here to debug), but my suggestion would be to clear your interval right before you start it, not after. So try the following:

```
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(function() {
    // do whatever here
}, time);
```

This way you make sure that whatever interval is ongoing is not ticking away anymore.

Comment: I did not mean to ask you guys to debug it, but I just wanted to understand what the logical issue is there and thus provided the script as I am unaware what the issue might be or which part would be relevant to the members. Anyhow, placing clearInterval outside doesn't make a difference to this issue.

Comment: If you place a clear right _before_ you start it there shouldn't be an interval anymore. Well, unless its locally declared, but altering global variables. Which, after re-reading your code, seems to be the case (interval is not declared outside your dom ready). Try what I said combined with declaring all your intervals as globally as the variables they change.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, that really was the problem. Can you please do me another favour, please tell me what was wrong with the question that people are getting pissed at me. I don't want to be doing that again.

Comment: Dont really know that.. I didn't downvote. You might want to isolate the problem a bit more next time! They usually also favor if oeople try themselves and post what they tried. I usually try to replicate the problem with as little code as possible. Helps to make sure you know where the problem lies!

Comment: thank you very much my good sir, placing it before did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is good to know what setinterval does.

So per example:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      //some code here
}
```

The value of the variable 'myInterval' is not a function as you might expect.
The value is however an integer.

So by setting off the interval again in your code this integer changes from (per example) 1 to 2. 
If you run do not clear the interval before you run it again, the only thing you will do is clearing the latest interval. The first one has not been cleared.

Also be careful where you run an interval, before you know it you already have a couple of them running in your script.

Comment: Thats very true, but apparently clearing the interval before setting it does not make a difference. It must be a scope thing. Interesting stuff though :)

Comment: @somethinghere I had not tried placing the clear "before" setting it but just outside which I changed now. Also I declared the variables outside and it works fine. All thanks to you guys at Stackoverflow.